# How do I compile myfile.py to myfile.exe with all packages I used in my code?

Tags: python, pycharm, pyinstaller

I've got a problem with my final .exe file. While writing code, I used package colorama and time, but the final compiled file doesn't include them. I use pyinstaller for compilations and PyCharm as IDL.

I've tried py2exe, updating all the packages I used.

from colorama import Fore
import time

I expect the fine-looking text, but the actual one while running file.exe is "\033[30m My text"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried PyInstaller? It packages all of your libraries that you used and turns it into an .exe

If you want to download it just do `pip install PyInstaller` assuming you are on windows. And if you want to turn your program into a .exe all you have to do is

`cd C:\Location\For\Your\Python\File`

and then run

`pyinstaller myscript.py`

Just make sure that your packages are installed on the python directory.

[Read more on this website](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/operating-mode.html)